# Primeng Inputtext: Cancel button functionality

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, cancel-button

I work on Angular 4 and I am using primgng `inputtext` and `dataTable`. My page shows a table with key and its value and my requirement is when I click on the `edit` button, the `value` field in the `dataTable` will start appearing  in the text field. When I `cancel` it should undo all the actions and show the original value of the text field and when I click on save I will make a service call to save it.

I am done with `Save` but `cancel` I am not able to figure out how to move ahead. Can any one please guide me how to implement cancel button functionality?

```
<button>Edit</button>
<button>Cancel</button>
<button>Save</button>

<p-dataTable [value]="fileInfo" [sortField]="sortF" [sortOrder]="sortO" (onSort)="changeSort($event)">
    <p-column field="key" header="Vin" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="value" header="Year" [sortable]="true">
    <ng-template let-col let-item="rowData">
            <input id="float-input" type="text" size="30" pInputText value-"{{item.value}}">
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-footer>
      <button type="button" label="Sort by Year" (click)="changeSort($event)" pButton></button>
    </p-footer>
</p-dataTable>

this.fileInfo = [{
    key: "Name",
    value: "ABC"
},
{
    key: "Age",
    value: "45"
},
{
    key: "Place",
    value: "NY"
},
{
    key: "Book",
    value: "A1"
},
{
    key: "Contact",
    value: "123456"
}

]
```

Comment: May be you need to save data into `temp` variable for cancel purpose

Answer (score 0):

When you `subscribing` then on `success store it in a variable`(or you can store it in two or more variables based on requirement) and this variable will store the data unless it is changed voluntarily by you or page is refeshed. So, when you `click on  cancel assign the data stored in the variable to datatable.`